# Iteration through JSON data in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

```
My JSON array look like this

[{ 
         label: "Hobbies", 
         datatype: "check", 
         lookupname: "null", 
         order: "05", 
         options: [
                    0:{id: "01", value: "Music"}
                    1:{id: "02", value: "Sports"}
                    2:{id: "02", value: "Travelling"}
                    3:{id: "02", value: "Reading"}
                  ]

 }]
```

I want a dropdown when click on hobbies with values in options

My HTML code

```
 <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="main2">
       <ion-item *ngIf='item.datatype == "check"' >
         <ion-label floating>{{item.label}}</ion-label>
                <ion-select>
                    <ion-option>{{item.options.value}}</ion-option>
                </ion-select>    
       </ion-item>
  </ng-template>
```

Note: main2 is my main array which contain so many objects

How to iterate through options(Hobbies)to get the value(options)as dropdown when click

Comment: is `options` an array or object? you use `[...]` but then give each entry an id `0:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 nested ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241634/angular2-nested-ngfor)

Comment: options is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `*ngFor="let opt of item.options"`  for `ion-option`

I have created a demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iteration-through-json-data-in-ionic-2?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html). 
I hope this will help/guide to you/others.

> HTML Code

```
<ion-content padding>
 <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="main2">
       <ion-item *ngIf='item.datatype == "check"' >
         <ion-label floating>{{item.label}}</ion-label>
                <ion-select>
                    <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of item.options" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.value}}</ion-option>
                </ion-select>    
       </ion-item>
  </ng-template>
</ion-content>
```